# Create a file whose name is determined by the Date

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use python to make a file that takes in the date and then creates a file with it. This program is going to run all day every day and every new day I want a new file to be made with that day date and then for the file to be used. I don't get why my code will not allow that to work.

The code shows that if the file does not open it will get a `FileNotFoundError` and then I have it make the file but it seems to not be making the time. However if I take `{date}` out it will make the file.

I've tested if it is `{date}` and it seems to be it but it is a string so I don't get it

```python
import time
import csv

timestr = time.localtime() # get time
date= time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", timestr)

filename = (f"Readings/Readings{date}.csv")

try: 
    f = open(filename, 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found, making file")
    with open(filename, 'w+') as file_object:
        writer = csv.writer(file_object)
        writer.writerow(['Test'])
        file_object.close()
else:
    print('yes')
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Readings/Readings09/18/2019.csv
File "/home/pi/Desktop/script/script.py", line 17, in <module> with open(filename, 'w+') as file_object:
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a Reading folder or Create one using os.makedirs

```
import time
import csv


timestr = time.localtime() # get time
date= time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y", timestr).replace('/','_')

filename = (f"Readings/Readings{date}.csv")

try: 
    f = open(filename, 'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found, making file")
    with open(filename, 'w+') as file_object:
        writer = csv.writer(file_object)
        writer.writerow(['Test'])
        file_object.close()
else:
    print('yes')
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. It considers it as a pathname. You can use backward slash `.replace('/','\\')` . But naming file with slashes is not appropriate. You can use either '_' or '-' to name a file.

Answer (score 0):

Because the date you're using contains slashes "`/`". You can try to use `os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)`, to create the subfolder before creating the file.

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: `Readings/Readings09/18/2019.csv` is actually the file 2019.csv in the folder: `Readings/Readings09/18/`.  `open` cannot write a file in a folder that does not exist. The command [makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) with the option `exist_ok=True` creates the subfolder and does not complain if it already exists. I'd definitely use @Life_is_complex convention to make the date string: order by year, month, day.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the / in the date part:
change this: "%m/%d/%Y" to "%m-%d-%Y"